# Calendar`s getActualMinimum returns wrong value

Tags: java, calendar

I need to compare a certain date to the current date/time to make sure that it comes before the first day/hour/min/sec of the current month. In order to implement this feature, a configure a `Calendar` instance using its `getActualMinimum` method, however, today (Thursday, 19/01/2023 - 10:40:18 BRT 2023), it presented a behavior that I have never faced before. Consider the following code:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("After instantiation:                  " + cal.getTime());
    
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    System.out.println("After configuring the Day of Month:   " + cal.getTime());
    
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    System.out.println("After configuring the Hour of day:    " + cal.getTime());
    
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
    System.out.println("After configuring the Minutes:        " + cal.getTime());
    
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
    System.out.println("After configuring the Seconds:        " + cal.getTime());
    
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    System.out.println("After configuring the Millis:         " + cal.getTime());
```

The code above, in the moment that this post is being created, would print to the console:

```
After instantiation:                  Thu Jan 19 10:40:18 BRT 2023
After configuring the Day of Month:   Sun Jan 01 10:40:18 BRT 2023
After configuring the Hour of day:    Sat Dec 31 23:40:18 BRT 2022
After configuring the Minutes:        Sat Dec 31 23:00:18 BRT 2022
After configuring the Seconds:        Sat Dec 31 23:00:00 BRT 2022
After configuring the Millis:         Sat Dec 31 23:00:00 BRT 2022
```

Could someone explain why, after configuring the Hour of day, the value was set to **23** and not **00**?

Edit: I`m using Java 8, specifically JDK 1.8.0_241

My current and default Time Zone is the *Horário Padrão de Brasília* (BRT or GMT-3)

Comment: This works just fine for me. But you should definitely be using new `java.time` classes for this

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior on Java 17 or Java 8. Can you please be specific about the version of Java you are running (vendor and version)?

Comment: Which is your default time zone? Is that BRT for Brasilia Time? America/Sao_Paulo??

Comment: Could this have to do with an outdated time zone database? I seem to remember that the summer time (DST) rules in Brazil were changed a few years ago, and I figure that if your Java has the old version, it just might give unexpected results like these.

Comment: @Ole V.V could be right. I'm starting to believe that this problem might be the result of a somewhat outdated Java version and some weird PC configurations. I'll try to run the same tests on a newer machine (a remote production server on São Paulo) and see what happens there.

Comment: If you have reasons not to switch to a newer Java version immediately, you can probably find a tool for updating the tz data in the Java installation that you have got. I believe this happens differently in Java implementations from different vendors, so search for how to do in your case.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

With `java.time`, the modern date-time API, you have [specialized types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) for different purposes. A very common type is `ZonedDateTime` which contains the information of the timezone along with the date and time information.

**Note**: Unlike `java.util` date-time types, `java.time` types are immutable i.e. you always get a new instance on setting a new value; therefore, like a `String`, you need to assign the new value to the reference if you want the reference to point to the new value.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Replace ZoneId.systemDefault() with the applicable ZoneId e.g.
        // ZoneId.of("America/New_York")
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(zdt);

        zdt = zdt.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
        System.out.println(zdt);

        zdt = zdt.withHour(LocalTime.MIN.getHour());
        System.out.println(zdt);

        zdt = zdt.withMinute(LocalTime.MIN.getMinute());
        System.out.println(zdt);

        zdt = zdt.withSecond(LocalTime.MIN.getSecond());
        System.out.println(zdt);

        zdt = zdt.with(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, LocalTime.MIN.getLong(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND));
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(zdt.format(formatter));

        // In a single statement
        String output = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth())
                .withHour(LocalTime.MIN.getHour())
                .withMinute(LocalTime.MIN.getMinute())
                .withSecond(LocalTime.MIN.getSecond())
                .with(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, LocalTime.MIN.getLong(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND))
                .format(formatter);
        System.out.println(output);

        // There is a better way if all you want is day-1 with minimum time
        zdt = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth())
                .atStartOfDay()
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(zdt.format(formatter));
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run**:

```
2023-01-19T16:50:43.811714Z[GMT]
2023-01-01T16:50:43.811714Z[GMT]
2023-01-01T00:50:43.811714Z[GMT]
2023-01-01T00:00:43.811714Z[GMT]
2023-01-01T00:00:00.811714Z[GMT]
2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/nIPvu7)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### In case you need a solution using the legacy API:

[`Calendar#getTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()) returns an instance of `java.util.Date` which is not a real date-time object; rather, it just contains the number of milliseconds from *January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT*. The [`Date#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()) applies the system's timezone to calculate the date-time and returns the same.

The way to get the date-time string with the desired timezone is by applying the timezone to the `SimpleDateFormat` and using it to format the instance of `java.util.Date`.

**Demo**:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("After instantiation:                  " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        System.out.println("After configuring the Day of Month:   " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        System.out.println("After configuring the Hour of day:    " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
        System.out.println("After configuring the Minutes:        " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
        System.out.println("After configuring the Seconds:        " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
        System.out.println("After configuring the Millis:         " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run**:

```
After instantiation:                  Thu Jan 19 15:29:38.381 UTC 2023
After configuring the Day of Month:   Sun Jan 01 15:29:38.381 UTC 2023
After configuring the Hour of day:    Sun Jan 01 00:29:38.381 UTC 2023
After configuring the Minutes:        Sun Jan 01 00:00:38.381 UTC 2023
After configuring the Seconds:        Sun Jan 01 00:00:00.381 UTC 2023
After configuring the Millis:         Sun Jan 01 00:00:00.000 UTC 2023
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/tqSSxl)

Comment: The java.time seems like an excellent solution. I will be looking foward to working with it and learning it in the near future. However, due to certain technical decisions (code standardization and legacy code - really old API...), I won't be able to use the new java.time solution. Anyways, I tried implementing your **In case you need a solution using the legacy API:** solution, but I had to change the Time Zone, or else it would give me the the time ++ 3 hours: `sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));`  
But it still resulted in the same problem...

Comment: @GuilhermeBarboza Glad to hear that you found it useful. Wish you more success!

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is caused by the default TimeZone of your PC , try adding this after you declare the Calnedar object

```
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: Can even instantiate, the calendar with a timezone `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`

Comment: I tried this solution but it still did not work. However, it printed a different result: `After configuring the Hour of day:    Sat Dec 31 21:14:13 BRT 2022`